# Filtering `git bisect` by using the start parameter doesn't seem to work?

Tags: git, git-bisect

I'm trying to filter all my `git bisect` requests so that I only test pr's where there are changes to a specific folder (say `iOS`) within my git folder.

My git folder structure contains several folders say `iOS`, `android`, `server`.

I run `git bisect start -- iOS/` but when I provide my good and bad commits with say `git bisect good my_good_commit` and `git bisect bad my_bad_commit` I end up testing a pr which has no changes in the `iOS` directory.

I tried checking the man page by running `man git-bisect` and it says

> You can further cut down the number of trials, if you know what part
> of the tree is involved in the problem you are tracking down, by
> specifying    path parameters when issuing the bisect start command:
>
> ```
> $ git bisect start -- arch/i386 include/asm-i386
> ```

Any ideas?

Comment: There’s not necessarily a problem with that (wrt the goal of minimizing the number of tests), as long as the commit *ranges* being tested have a balance of commits that change `iOS`.